# How can I convert a subprocess.call(["cp", "-r", ...]) to work on Windows 10?

Tags: python

My goal is to use a code that another researcher gave to me. I am on Python 3.7 on Windows 10. I assume that the code is written for Python 2 and Linux OS.

I need to translate some of the old Python 2 commands to my new 3.7 version. I cannot use another Python version, or change my OS. I have started the job, and some of the translation are quite obvious, but I need your help for this one.

The old command is:

```
subprocess.call(["cp", "-r", WD + "Albedo", WD + "CIE_data",
                 WD + "Gases", WD + "Solar", ProcessDir[ProcessNumber]])
```

`WD` and `ProcessDir[ProcessNumber]` are both file paths.

I need a new command for Python 3.7 on Window 10. I assume that `"cp -r"` is equivalent to the Windows command `xcopy`, but my problem is the following: `WD + "Albedo"`, `+ "CIE_data"`, etc. How to `xcopy` several files in one command with `subprocess.call`?

Comment: Showing what you tried *and how it failed* (meaning the specific error message you get from xcopy, or the exception you get when trying to use it if an exception is thrown) would be helpful. Also, keep in mind that many of your readers here in the Python tag are not Windows users, may have never heard of `xcopy`, and are not likely to know how it's supposed to be called.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to copy multiple folders under `WD` to `ProcessDir[ProcessNumber]`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist ; yes I trying to copy multipke folders under WD with ProcessDir ; using subprocess.call

Comment: The proper way to show thanks is to select an answer and remove your question from the unanswered queue. That being said, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, there's no good reason to use *any* OS-provided tool for this when Python's `shutil` module gives you an OS-independent way to copy a directory tree. Thus:

```
import shutil, os.path

for subdir in ['Albedo' 'CIE_data' 'Gases', 'Solar']:
  shutil.copytree(os.path.join(WD, subdir),
                  os.path.join(ProcessDir[ProcessNumber], subdir))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I'm still going to post though

Comment: Is it worth noting that the files copied with `shutil` lose owner, group and other metadata?

Comment: @cody, so do files copied with `cp -r` without `-a`, so that was original behavior as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...usually, I consider posting an answer with essentially-duplicative code bad form, but you did a great job at adding useful explanations; no room to begrudge.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. I appreciate the endorsement. I started working on this well before you posted your answer, so it really is a good example of the idea of having one obvious way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously recommend not copying files like that. As you see in your current situation, you are not guaranteed to have the same program available on different machines. On the other hand, you have Python, which has all the cross-platform file-copying utilities you will likely need.

For generic file operations, the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module is your friend. In particular, [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) does what you want almost exactly. The only difference is that the destination may not already exist, and you have to copy one source folder at a time.

Another point is that you generally don't want to concatenate paths that may or may not contain a trailing slash with `+`. Use [`os.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead. It will not only handle such differences, but make sure that the path separator it inserts is correct for your OS.

In total you have:

```
from shutil import copytree
from os.path import join

for folder in ('Albedo', 'CIE Data', 'Gasses', 'Solar'):
    copytree(join(WD, folder), join(ProcessDir[ProcessNumber], folder))
```

If something goes wrong along the way, you may want to pre-clean your output using [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree). Before calling `copytree`, do

```
rmtree(join(ProcessDir[ProcessNumber], folder), ignore_errors=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for all answers ^^